# HttpErrorResponse - Angular

Tags: c#, angular, http, asp.net-web-api

```
 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/Active_Serviced_Outlets?Year=2021&quarter=1&month=1', ok: false, …}
```

Getting Status 500 error. Thanks in advance.

.Net Core Controller Not calling this method while checking with Breakpoint
[image]

TotSalesAmtController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vantage.Core.Direct.BL;
using Vantage.Core.Direct.DAL.Models;

namespace Vantage.Core.Direct.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Active_Serviced_Outlets")]
    // [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ActServOutlsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly VantageContext _context;
        public ActServOutlsController(VantageContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        //[Route("Get")]
        public decimal? Get(string Year, string quarter, string month)
        {
            var value = new ActServOutlsMgt().GetById(Year, quarter, month, _context);
            return value;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your Angular Http url should be `https://localhost:44361/api/Total_Sales_Amount?Year=2021&quarter=1&month=1`, but not `https://localhost:44361/api/Active_Serviced_Outlets?Year=2021&quarter=1&month=1` according to the Controller route **api/Total_Sales_Amount**.

Comment: go to the `Network tab` in browsers `Devtools` and inspect the response.